# Using SVG inside polymer element

Tags: svg, dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to use an SVG file with symbols, but it doesn't work inside a polymer element.

This is the code I use:

```
<svg class="icon-home"><use xlink:href="/images/icons.svg#icon-home"></use></svg>
```

It works perfectly fine in my `index.html` but just doesn't display the icon when used inside the polymer template.

If I take the contents of `/images/icons.svg` and put it directly in the polymer element it works. (I'm sure that the path is correct though)

Any idea on what could be the problem?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I just created a `<svg-icon>` polymer element, that just inlines the contents of the `.svg` file. It works but it seems to me that it's more a workaround than a solution.